# flexible search query return null in java file but working fine in hac

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to fetch some data through a method. My query is working fine in hac but it result null when used in java code. Below is my java code:-

```
 public class abc
 {
        @Resource
     private UserService userService;
     @Resource
     private SearchRestrictionService searchRestrictionService;
     @Resource
     private CatalogVersionService catalogVersionService;

         public List<ProductModel> findRequiredProducts()
         {
             this.userService.setCurrentUser(userService.getAdminUser());
             this.searchRestrictionService.disableSearchRestrictions();
                 this.catalogVersionService.setSessionCatalogVersion("abcCatalog", "Online");
          final String query = "select {p:name},{p.creationtime} from {Product! as p}";
          final FlexibleSearchQuery productQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
          final SearchResult<ProductModel> searchResult = getFlexibleSearchService().search(productquery);
          this.searchRestrictionService.enableSearchRestrictions();
         final List<ProductModel> requiredProducts = searchResult.getResult();

         }

 }
```

Here on executing this code I am getting lazylist[null]" in requiredProduct list. What may be the issue.

Comment: What about FlexibleSearchQuery???

Comment: @JayPrakashKumar I have defined the query which I am executing on hac in String query .I have passed this string(query) in flexibleSearchQueryobject. I dont get you what your are asking

Comment: what does  this line : final FlexibleSearchQuery productQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);

Comment: @JayPrakashKumar Sir to use flexibleSEArchService in hybris , I think it is necessary to pass query in flexibleSearchQuery object. Without this eclipse is showing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the flexible search service the only attribute you should be interested in is the primary key, the issue here is that the flexible search service will try to transform the name (*String*) into a PK (*long*), try with the following code (Groovy script) :

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult

def userService = spring.getBean("userService")
def searchRestrictionService = spring.getBean("searchRestrictionService")
def catalogVersionService = spring.getBean("catalogVersionService")
def flexibleSearchService = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService")

userService.setCurrentUser(userService.getAdminUser())

def query = "select {pk} from {Product! as p}"
FlexibleSearchQuery productQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
def searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(productQuery);
def requiredProducts = searchResult.getResult();
```

**Remember that ! means you won't load any subtypes**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but my project does not allow me to include groovy script. Can you suggest me what changes do i need to make in my java code without including groovy script.

Comment: *select {pk} from {Product! as p}* all other attributes would be loaded inside your model object no need to select them individually.